SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from <LINK>
Oi!
Preciso de ajuda com esse código que estou escrevendo para GNRE do Espírito Santo, utilizando o padrão SOAP (versão 1.2), estou programando em PHP (versão 7.2.24), e está dando esse erro:SOAP Error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL : Couldn't load from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' : failed to load external entity "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/", segue o código:
<?php

function verificarExtensoesNecessarias() {
    $extensoes = ['soap', 'openssl', 'xml'];
    foreach ($extensoes as $ext) {
        if (!extension_loaded($ext)) {
            die("E01 Extensão $ext do PHP não instalada.");
        }
    }
}

function validarParametros($argc, $argv) {
    if ($argc != 5) {
        die("E01 Parâmetros incorretos para execução: php {$argv[0]} <ação> <arquivo_xml> <certificado_pfx> <senha>");
    }

    $acao = $argv[1];
    if (!in_array($acao, ['emissao', 'pdf'])) {
        die("E01 Ação inválida: $acao");
    }

    return $acao;
}

function validarArquivos($arqXML, $arqCert, $certCA) {
    if (!file_exists($arqXML)) {
        die("E01 Arquivo XML não encontrado: $arqXML");
    }

    if (!is_readable($arqXML)) {
        die("E01 Arquivo XML sem acesso para leitura: $arqXML");
    }

    if (!file_exists($arqCert)) {
        die("E01 Certificado não encontrado: $arqCert");
    }

if (!is_readable($arqCert)) {
        die("E01 Certificado sem acesso para leitura: $arqCert");
    }

    if (!file_exists($certCA)) {
        die("E01 Certificado CA não encontrado: $certCA");
    }

    if (!is_readable($certCA)) {
        die("E01 Certificado CA sem acesso para leitura: $certCA");
    }
}

function criarContextoSSL($certCA) {
    return stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => true,
            'verify_peer_name' => true,
            'allow_self_signed' => false,
            'cafile' => $certCA,
            'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
        ]
    ]);
}

function configurarClienteSOAP($arqCert, $senhaCert, $contextoSSL) {
    return [
        'local_cert' => $arqCert,
        'passphrase' => $senhaCert,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'trace' => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'stream_context' => $contextoSSL,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout' => 60,
        'exceptions' => true
    ];
}

function processarRespostaSOAP($client, $arqXML) {
    try {
        // Lê o conteúdo do arquivo XML
        $xmlContent = file_get_contents($arqXML);

        // Prepara o corpo da mensagem SOAP
        $params = [
            'duaDadosMsg' => $xmlContent
        ];

        // Envia a requisição
        $response = $client->duaObterPdf($params);

        // Processa a resposta
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($client->__getLastResponse());
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('duae', 'http://www.sefaz.es.gov.br/duae');

        // Extrai os campos relevantes
        $retorno = $xml->xpath('//duae:retObterPdfDua')[0];
        $cStat = (string)$retorno->cStat;
        $xMotivo = (string)$retorno->xMotivo;

        if ($cStat != '106') {
            die("E01 Não foi possí­vel obter PDF do DUA. cStat: $cStat - Motivo: $xMotivo");
        }

        // Extrai e salva o PDF
        $pdfBase64 = (string)$retorno->xPdf;
        $pdfContent = base64_decode($pdfBase64);

        // Gera nome do arquivo de saída
        $outputFile = dirname($arqXML) . '/' . basename($arqXML, '.xml') . '.pdf';

        if (file_put_contents($outputFile, $pdfContent) === false) {
            die("E01 Não foi possí­vel salvar arquivo PDF do DUA: $outputFile");
        }

        echo "PDF do DUA salvo com sucesso em: $outputFile";
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        $mensagem = "E01 Falha no serviço SOAP: " . $e->getMessage() . " Última requisição: " . (isset($client) ? $client->__getLastRequest() : '');
        logErro($mensagem, $arqXML);
        die("$mensagem");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $mensagem = "E01 Falha geral: " . $e->getMessage();
        logErro($mensagem, $arqXML);
        die("$mensagem");
    }
}

function logErro($mensagem, $arqXML) {
    // Gera nome do arquivo de saída
    $arqLog = dirname($arqXML) . '/' . basename($arqXML, '.xml') . '.log';
    $dataHorario = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    file_put_contents($arqLog, "[$dataHorario] $mensagem\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

// Início do Script
verificarExtensoesNecessarias();

$acao = validarParametros($argc, $argv);
$arqXML = $argv[2];
$arqCert = $argv[3];
$senhaCert = $argv[4];

// Ajuste de caminho relativo
if (substr($arqCert, 0, 2) == '..') {
    $arqCert = '/var/www' . substr($arqCert, 2);
}
$arqCert = str_replace('//', '/', $arqCert);

$certCA = '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt';

validarArquivos($arqXML, $arqCert, $certCA);

$contextoSSL = criarContextoSSL($certCA);
$options = configurarClienteSOAP($arqCert, $senhaCert, $contextoSSL);

try {
    // Define o WSDL
    $wsdl = 'https://app.sefaz.es.gov.br/WsDua/DuaService.asmx?wsdl';

    // Cria o cliente SOAP
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

    // Prepara o cabeçalho SOAP
    $header = new SoapHeader(
        'http://www.sefaz.es.gov.br/duae',
        'duaServiceHeader',
        ['versao' => '1.01']
    );
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    processarRespostaSOAP($client, $arqXML);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $mensagem = "E01 Falha ao configurar cliente SOAP: " . $e->getMessage();
    logErro($mensagem, $arqXML);
    die("$mensagem");
}

?>

